# Why does this program produce a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

My logic behind this program is.

If the gtin != 8 and it is only integers it will print an error make sure the length of the barcode is 8
If the gtin = not integers it will print only digits allowed
The user needs to press enter to continue the program however I keep getting a syntax error
Sorry for bad english as it is not my first language

```
def get_user_input():
    """ get input from user """
    GTIN = 0
    while True:
        try:
            GTIN = int(input("input your gtin-8 number:"))
            if len(str(GTIN)) == 8:
                break
            else:
                print("make sure the length of the barcode is 8")
            elif:
                GTIN=(""):
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("only digits allowed")
    return GTIN
def search_user_input():
```

This is not a duplicate , as I progressed in my program and now I have found another problem which I am unsure of how to fix

Comment: `GTIN=(""):` remove the colon (`:`)

Comment: Yea but the `elif` after the `else` doesn't make sense too....

Comment: Try this code here: https://gist.github.com/kingmak/0363657db3290b4f24b277a8ebbe0d66

Comment: The very last line produces a syntax error,where you call the function